# GNU Octave load sparse matrix

Tags: matrix, octave, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to get used to Octave.

After loading a `.mat` file containing a sparse matrix (you can get it here https://sparse.tamu.edu [bcspwr01]) I'm not able to do anything with it.

Tryed commands like `full`, `cell2mat`, etc. but it throws errors.

What I want to do is use `inv()` or `det()` on it.

How do I achieve this?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mat file is a Matlab data format for storing one or more workspace variables.  The file you're trying to open contains the data you want, but it has more than just the sparse dataset.  It is a structure that includes the data and a number of other meta-data fields.

After saving the `bcspwr01.mat` file, you can load it into the Octave workspace with the command:

```
load bcspwr01.mat
```

If you are using the Octave GUI, you will see the Workspace now lists a variable named `Problem` of class `struct`. If you are just using the command line interface, you can see a list of workspace variables with the command `whos`.  A [structure object](https://octave.org/doc/v6.2.0/Structures.html) contains a number of named fields that can be individually addressed to access the contents.  In this case it contains the fields `title`, `A`, `name`, `id`, `date`, `author`, `ed`, and `kind`.  The structure can be displayed just by calling it from the command line as follows:

```
>> Problem
Problem =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    title = SYMMETRIC STRUCTURE (STANDARD TEST POWER SYSTEM - NEW ENGLAND)
    A =

Compressed Column Sparse (rows = 39, cols = 39, nnz = 131 [8.6%])

  (1, 1) -> 1
  (2, 1) -> 1
  (39, 1) -> 1
  (1, 2) -> 1
  (2, 2) -> 1
  (3, 2) -> 1
  (25, 2) -> 1
  (30, 2) -> 1
  (2, 3) -> 1
  (3, 3) -> 1
  (4, 3) -> 1
  (18, 3) -> 1
  (3, 4) -> 1
  (4, 4) -> 1
  (14, 4) -> 1
  (18, 4) -> 1
  (5, 5) -> 1
  (6, 5) -> 1
  (8, 5) -> 1
  (5, 6) -> 1
  (6, 6) -> 1
  (7, 6) -> 1
  (11, 6) -> 1
  (31, 6) -> 1
  (6, 7) -> 1
  (7, 7) -> 1
  (8, 7) -> 1
  (5, 8) -> 1
  (7, 8) -> 1
  (8, 8) -> 1
  (9, 8) -> 1
  (8, 9) -> 1
  (9, 9) -> 1
  (39, 9) -> 1
  (10, 10) -> 1
  (11, 10) -> 1
  (13, 10) -> 1
  (32, 10) -> 1
  (6, 11) -> 1
  (10, 11) -> 1
  (11, 11) -> 1
  (12, 11) -> 1
  (11, 12) -> 1
  (12, 12) -> 1
  (13, 12) -> 1
  (10, 13) -> 1
  (12, 13) -> 1
  (13, 13) -> 1
  (14, 13) -> 1
  (4, 14) -> 1
  (13, 14) -> 1
  (14, 14) -> 1
  (15, 14) -> 1
  (14, 15) -> 1
  (15, 15) -> 1
  (16, 15) -> 1
  (15, 16) -> 1
  (16, 16) -> 1
  (17, 16) -> 1
  (19, 16) -> 1
  (21, 16) -> 1
  (24, 16) -> 1
  (16, 17) -> 1
  (17, 17) -> 1
  (18, 17) -> 1
  (27, 17) -> 1
  (3, 18) -> 1
  (4, 18) -> 1
  (17, 18) -> 1
  (18, 18) -> 1
  (16, 19) -> 1
  (19, 19) -> 1
  (20, 19) -> 1
  (33, 19) -> 1
  (19, 20) -> 1
  (20, 20) -> 1
  (34, 20) -> 1
  (16, 21) -> 1
  (21, 21) -> 1
  (22, 21) -> 1
  (21, 22) -> 1
  (22, 22) -> 1
  (23, 22) -> 1
  (35, 22) -> 1
  (22, 23) -> 1
  (23, 23) -> 1
  (24, 23) -> 1
  (36, 23) -> 1
  (16, 24) -> 1
  (23, 24) -> 1
  (24, 24) -> 1
  (2, 25) -> 1
  (25, 25) -> 1
  (26, 25) -> 1
  (37, 25) -> 1
  (25, 26) -> 1
  (26, 26) -> 1
  (27, 26) -> 1
  (28, 26) -> 1
  (29, 26) -> 1
  (17, 27) -> 1
  (26, 27) -> 1
  (27, 27) -> 1
  (26, 28) -> 1
  (28, 28) -> 1
  (29, 28) -> 1
  (26, 29) -> 1
  (28, 29) -> 1
  (29, 29) -> 1
  (38, 29) -> 1
  (2, 30) -> 1
  (30, 30) -> 1
  (6, 31) -> 1
  (31, 31) -> 1
  (10, 32) -> 1
  (32, 32) -> 1
  (19, 33) -> 1
  (33, 33) -> 1
  (20, 34) -> 1
  (34, 34) -> 1
  (22, 35) -> 1
  (35, 35) -> 1
  (23, 36) -> 1
  (36, 36) -> 1
  (25, 37) -> 1
  (37, 37) -> 1
  (29, 38) -> 1
  (38, 38) -> 1
  (1, 39) -> 1
  (9, 39) -> 1
  (39, 39) -> 1

    name = HB/bcspwr01
    id = 13
    date = 1981
    author = B. Dembart, J. Lewis
    ed = I. Duff, R. Grimes, J. Lewis
    kind = power network problem
```

`A` contains your data.  Access this as a variable you can manipulate by typing:

```
>> Problem.A
ans =

Compressed Column Sparse (rows = 39, cols = 39, nnz = 131 [8.6%])
                                                                                                
  (1, 1) -> 1
  (2, 1) -> 1
  ...
```

at this point you can assign it to another variable or work with it directly.

```
>> full(Problem.A)
ans =

 Columns 1 through 24:

   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   1
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
 Columns 25 through 39:

   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
   1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0
   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

or

```
>> ABC = Problem.A;
>> det(ABC)
ans = -12.000
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much :)